# ElasticSearch document structure to not index https/http separately

Tags: c#, elasticsearch, nest

I've been building an ElasticSearch "web page" index which will be used to power online site search.  I have a C# class that I've built and decorated with some Nest attributes, but I'm still a little unsure that I've got everything covered I might need.

This is my class:

```
[ElasticType(IdProperty = "url_id")]
public class WebPage
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Thee last time this document was indexed
    /// </summary>
    public string dateScanned { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// The ACTUAL mime type returned.  Can be something like application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.presentationml.presentation
    /// </summary>
    [ElasticProperty(Index = FieldIndexOption.NotAnalyzed)] //so we can do aggregates / faceted search on it
    public string mimeType { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Human-friendly type.  Like: HTML, DOC, PPT
    /// </summary>
    [ElasticProperty(Index = FieldIndexOption.NotAnalyzed)] //so we can do aggregates / faceted search on it
    public string shortMimeType { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// The URL without protocol.  Prevents indexing http:// and https:// as two separate index pages
    /// This is used as the ID field in ES.
    /// </summary>
    public string url_id { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// The url we use when building a link.  DOES include protocol
    /// </summary>
    public string url { get; set; }

    //the rest are your standard fields for a simple "document"
    public string body { get; set; }
    public string keywords { get; set; }
    public string description { get; set; }
    public string title { get; set; }
}
```

A problem I've encountered is that if I use the full URL for the ElasticSearch ID, I might end up with two entries for the same page.  i.e.

- http://www.example.com/
- https://www.example.com/

To prevent this I've decided to store the url in the "url_id" field without the protocol (www.example.com/ in the examples above) and use that as the ES identifier. Then I'll also store the full URL in the "url" field, this will be the one that gets printed to the page during a query.

The problem I see is that sometimes the url field will point to http and other times to https - it'll be whichever one was indexed "last".

Is there a better way to handle the protocol storage issue?

Comment: Could you clarify why such behavior is a problem and what would be an ideal behavior in your case?

Comment: It's a search engine so I was hoping to eliminate what are essentially duplicate results from appearing in the result set and only have one result per unique "content" appear to the user.

Comment: Yes, and you achieved it by chopping off protocol in "url_id". So, what is the problem?

Comment: Could always make url a collection e.g. `HashSet<string>` and store both https and http. Also, you may want to think about setting up appropriate analysis for the url field using e.g. path hierarchy tokenizer or UAX Email Url tokenizer, depending on how you are anticipating to search the documents.

Comment: @imotov - I guess there is no problem, but I was worried there was something basic I was overlooking, thanks.

Comment: @RussCam - that's also a great idea on the tokenizer, thanks as well!  Also, thanks for all the help in general guys, this is my first time dealing with Elastic so I was very unsure of my design.